# Cursor out of bounds exception

Tags: android, cursor, radio-button

I am fetching data from cursor. Using this cursor i am populating the text for my radio button. While displaying the activity it works fine but when i try to select the radio button, i again try to access my cursor and at that time i get the cursor out of bounds exception. Please help me out.

```
Cursor cur=db.getForcemodLevelForMenuitem(mnuItmID);            
   cur.moveToFirst();
   while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
     cnt=1;
     //Level 1
     if(cur.getInt(0)==1)
      {
       LinearLayout level1Layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.level1Layout);
       level1Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   //ArrayList menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1=db.GetBaseObjectListFromDBWhere("MenuitemForcemodMapping", "MenuitemID= "+mnuItmID+ " and Level="+1);                    
        menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1=db.getForcemodDetailsForMenuitem(mnuItmID,1);
        RadioGroup level1_rg=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.level1_rg);
        RadioButton[] rblevel1=new RadioButton[menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.getCount()];

        menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.moveToFirst();                   
            int i=0;
            while (menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.isAfterLast() == false) { 

            rblevel1[i] =new RadioButton(AddPopupMenuItem.this);
            rblevel1[i].setText(menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.getString(1).substring(0));              
            rblevel1[i].setTextColor(R.color.black);                        
            level1_rg.addView(rblevel1[i]);
            rblevel1[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                     

              @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                  menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.moveToPosition(i);
                  forceModNameList.add(menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.getString(1).substring(0));
                           }
                        });
                           i++;
                           menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.moveToNext();
                           }                    
                           menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.close();
                           rblevel1=null;
                         }
                       }
                        cur.moveToNext();
                      }
                     cur.close();
                     db.close();
                   } 
                 }
```

I am getting error at this line

```
 :forceModNameList.add(menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.getString(1).substring(0));
```

Thanks ,
Neha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already retreive the 1st element at :

> rblevel1[i].setText(menuitemForcemodMapsLevel1.getString(1).substring(0));

so the cursor is moved ahead. And then you are asking again the same thing to retrieve. Cursor can't move backwards, it moves only forward by default. So you are getting this error.

Why don't you save the value in a `String` and can thus use again without the need of retreiving it again.

I beleive this will simplify your code and also solve the problem. Try out.

Answer (score 0):

please use this, i think it will solve your issue

```
    Cursor c;
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
      do
       {
        // perform operation in this blocks

       }while(c.moveToNext());
     }
```

Comment: let me know if u have any doubt

Comment: You should check the call to moveToFirst(). If it returns false, the cursor is empty and you shouldn't enter the do-while loop.

Comment: yes Samuel, sorry for that . this time is leaving the office so its very urgent reply so

Comment: @RameshSolanki & Samuel, I believe here the issue is not of cursor being empty, as he is retrieving the 1st element once and the error is occuring on trying to retrieve the same element again. So that is the problem.